# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on instance variable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

In MyClass.m file:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *myDict;
}
```

Then the initialization:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    myDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSLog(@"address1: %p", myDict);
    return self;
}
```

And then later on:

```
NSLog(@"address2: %p", myDict);
NSLog(@"crash: %@", myDict);
```

This code crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the last NSLog line. Here's the output:

```
address1: 0x6080000483a0
address2: 0x6080000483a8
```

So the init does get called and it gets called only once. But the object myDict somehow gets lost at the original address in memory. Then when I try to access it (the "crash: " output line) I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

What's going on here?

Comment: Please add the class interface and the code that causes the exception to your Q.

Comment: Set an exception break point to be sure the crash is where you think it is.  Post the code and some NSLog output at the point of the crash.

Comment: are you sure you are using the init method to create MyClass instance? Maybe you have some other initializers? And generally, don't use instance variables, use properties.

Comment: Possibly, some objet in the dictionnary is causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Nicolas But why does the myDict object prior to the EXC_BAD_ACCESS change its address?

Comment: No idea, I can't see all of your code ;-)